# Compile LLVM on Travis-ci

Tags: clang, llvm, travis-ci, llvm-clang

I need to compile a project against LLVM/Clang 3.9.1 built with some particular flags (`RTTI` and `CXX1Y`), so in my .travis.yml I firstly download LLVM/Clang 3.9 source, then I build it as I need and finally I install it in `/usr/bin`.

When (after this phase) I try to run `llvm-config --version` and `clang --version` I discover that the version 5.0.0 is considered.

Is there a way to run a build on travis-ci without LLVM/Clang to be installed or a way to set the version 3.9.1 as the default `llvm-config` and `clang` executables?

Comment: Sounds like a [customer service question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/fnord).

Comment: It sounds like a toolchain problem. Why not specify the direct path to LLVM 3.9 clang in the compilation settings? If this is CMake, you need `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. If this is custom scripts, just provide custom path to the `clang`. Going with `clang` directly is causing conflicts with the clang installed on Travis' machine.

Comment: Thank you @StanislavPankevich, I configure with CMake and using CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and I am able to pass exactly the version I need.

Answer (score 1):

Travis CI can be built without any preinstalled `C/C++` compilers (e.g. set `language: ruby` in your `.travis.yml` file) but the better/safer way might be to specify your compiler explicitly in your build system. Like Stanislav mentioned in a comment, you could use `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` if you use `CMake`.